# Why is expanded widget is destroying my UI in flutter after publishing it on play store

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, google-play-console

I have developed an application in Flutter Dart and used an Expanded widget in my application but wherever I used expanded widget, it destroyed my UI and converted that List into an infinite list with no data on it.

Please let me know that reason why does this occur and the potential solution.

Thank you everyone in advance

Comment: Your expanded widget might be in a scrollView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the expanded widget inside the column and row. Sometimes with use of an expanded widget with the wrong widget will give the error in release mode while it is working in the debug mode.

Make sure you are using the expanded widget inside the column or row and that column and row should not be inside the scroll view or other scrollable widgets.

If still not clear then update the question with the widget hierarchy.